# PHP - Dropzone doesn't work on server but works on localhost

Tags: javascript, php, image, server, drag-and-drop

I have to use the Dropzone.js in a university final project and I'm having some issues. The problem is that the program works fine on localhost but doesn't work on the university server. I'm using a dropzone script that redirects to this code:

```
function msubirimagendropzone(){
        $storeFolder = '/imagenes/vinos/';   //2
        $nombreimagen = $_POST["nombrevino"];

        if (!empty($_FILES)) {

            $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];          //3       
            $tipo_imagen=$_FILES['file']['type'];
            $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $storeFolder;  //4
            imagepng($tempFile, $nombreimagen);
            $targetFile =  $targetPath. $nombreimagen;  //5
            move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile. ".png"); //6
            smart_resize_image($targetFile.".png",null,200,200,false,$targetFile . "_little.png",false,false,100);
            smart_resize_image($targetFile.".png",null,500,500,false,$targetFile . "_medium.png",false,false,100);
            smart_resize_image($targetFile.".png",null,1000,1000,false,$targetFile . "_big.png",false,false,100);
        }
    }
```

I want to upload the image but with .png type. After uploading it, I want to resize it. But the program doesn't upload anything to the path target.

Comment: Check your path permissions and put here.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because your path is wrong.
Update: `$storeFolder = '/imagenes/vinos/';`
To the full path on your university server.

Also, you might want to use full quotes:
`$storeFolder = "/imagenes/vinos/";`

Comment: An idea would be to use `if` statement to check for the files in that folder, to see if they are there. If they are there, set a custom message. It will help you debug the script.

Comment: If this was the correct answer, could you mark it as the solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
if(!empty($_FILES)){

//database configuration
$dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbUsername = 'root';
$dbPassword = '';
$dbName = 'codexworld';
//connect with the database
$conn = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
if($mysqli->connect_errno){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

$targetDir = "uploads/";
$fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$targetFile = $targetDir.$fileName;

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$targetFile)){
    //insert file information into db table
    $conn->query("INSERT INTO files (file_name, uploaded) VALUES('".$fileName."','".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."')");
}
```

}
?>

Comment: please consider explaining the OP *why** you give this code, not just write raw code. It'll improve your answer and help later when newcomers will search SO